# Can i use ReactiveCocoa in swift 3?

Tags: ios, swift3, reactive-cocoa, rx-swift

I have to use Reactive Cocoa or RxSwift in the following code for dynamic label height and dynamic row height.

Can I use Reactive Cocoa in Swift3? And What is the difference between ReactiveCocoa and RxSwift?

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell: BTSTableViewCell = self.tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "BTSTableViewCellIdentifier")! as! BTSTableViewCell

    cell.configureWithPost(posts[indexPath.row])
    cell.delegate = self
    return cell

}
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {

    // 259.5+ labelHeight+ bigImageHeight

    let postViewModel = posts[indexPath.row]

    //caption height
    var captionHeight = postViewModel.textDetail?.height(withConstrainedWidth: tableView.bounds.size.width - 20, font: UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 17))

    captionHeight = ceil(captionHeight!)

    var finalCaptionHeight: CGFloat = 0.0;

    if postViewModel.showDetailedCaption {
        finalCaptionHeight = captionHeight!
    }
    else {
        finalCaptionHeight = min(41, captionHeight!)
    }
    return 259.5 + postViewModel.getBigImageHeightFor(tableView.bounds.size.width) + finalCaptionHeight

}
```

Comment: @Peres answers your question, but I am wondering, why do you think you "have to use Reactive Cocoa or RxSwift [...] for dynamic label height and dynamic row height"?

Comment: @Sebastian Actually, I need to use it because it's my requirement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Can I use Reactive Cocoa in Swift3?

Yes you can. The project is [located here](https://github.com/ReactiveCocoa/ReactiveCocoa). It's important to note that ReactiveCocoa will only have the UI bindings, while the actual "engine" is called [ReactiveSwift](https://github.com/ReactiveCocoa/ReactiveSwift).

> And What is the difference between ReactiveCocoa and RxSwift?

You can find a comparison [here](https://www.raywenderlich.com/126522/reactivecocoa-vs-rxswift). But bottom line, both are two very capable frameworks. You won't get it wrong independently of which one you pick.

Comment: Thank you. Can you help me to convert the above code into RxSwift?

Comment: @Bharath that's besides the scope of your question. Please mark this answer as corrected (if you deem so) and open a new question.